# How to call protocol with multiple classes within the same file (.m) in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, multiple-instances

I have an `UITableViewCell`'s subclass (Say, `MyTableViewCell`).

Inside `MyTableViewCell`'s implementation, I have a subclass of `UIView` (Say, `MyView`) where I drew all needed stuffs. I assigned `MyView` to the `MyTableViewCell`'s content view.

See the code for better clarification:

> MyTableViewCell.h

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
   ...
   ...
}

@property ...
@property ...

@end
```

> MyTableViewCell.m

```
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"

@interface MyView : UIView //Interface of MyView
{
    MyTableViewCell *myCell;
    ...
}

@end


@implementation MyView //Implementation of MyView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame cell:(MyTableViewCell *)cell
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        myCell = cell;
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   ... //Drawing stuffs
}

...
...

-(void)eventOccured
{
   //I want to call a method doNeedful() of MyTableViewCell here.
}


@end


@interface MyTableViewCell() //private variables of cell
{
    UIView *myView;
}

@end


@implementation MyTableViewCell

@synthesize ...

-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self)
    {
        myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds cell:self];
        ...
        [self.contentView addSubview:myView];
    }

    return self;
}

...
...

-(void)doNeedful
{
}

@end
```

**Question:**

I want to call the `doNeedful`() method in `MyTableViewCell` class when `MyView`'s `eventOccured`() was called.

I tried to create protocol but failed in all ways. Can someone help me to know how to define protocol to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you show the protocol that you wrote that "failed in all ways"? There are already lots of questions about protocols so it's difficult to tell exactly what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this code

```
@interface MyView : UIView //Interface of MyView
{
    MyTableViewCell *myCell;
    ...
}
```

add below code

```
 @interface MyView : UIView //Interface of MyView
   @property(nonatomic,assign) id mycell// It should be assign or weak bcoz cell is the parent
```

in your method

```
-(void)eventOccured
{

[self.myCell doNeedful];
}
```

When allocating

```
 myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds cell:self];
myview.myCell = self;
  [self.contentView addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Is this "@protocol" or "@property"? Tried with @property and its not working :(

Comment: "myview.myCell = self;" this line shows an error "Property 'myCell' not found on object of type 'UIView'"

Comment: @property(nonatomic,assign) id mycell i should be id type

Comment: add screenshot of the issue you face